# Programmatically remove an app deployed on an eclipse custom IServer that extends from ServerDelegate

Tags: java, server, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I wonder if there in eclipse RCP a programmatically way to remove an app deployed to a custom server that extends from a `ServerDelegate`, just like it is done with the existing functionality **Add and Remove...**, available doing right click on the server.
I understand that the deployed app is into an IModule and this IModule is into the IServer.
I already tried with the method `modifyModules(IModule[] add, IModule[] remove, IProgressMonitor monitor)` but I only achieved to stop the app running, but nevertheless the app continue attached to the module and this to the server.

Comment: What are `ServerDelegate`, `IServer` and `IModule`? None of these is part of the core Eclipse RCP code.

Comment: Oh sorry, these belongs to **eclipse WST**, [ServerDelegate](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/api/org/eclipse/wst/server/core/model/ServerDelegate.html), [IModule](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/api/org/eclipse/wst/server/core/IModule.html), [IServer](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/api/org/eclipse/wst/server/core/IServer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use the modifyModules from the ServerWorkingCopy?

The documentation form the [modifyModules](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/api/org/eclipse/wst/server/core/model/ServerDelegate.html#modifyModules(org.eclipse.wst.server.core.IModule[],%20org.eclipse.wst.server.core.IModule[],%20IProgressMonitor)) method on the ServerDelegate states:

This method is called by the web server core framework, in response to a call to IServerWorkingCopy.modifyModules

So seems that the modifyModules form the ServerDelegate it's called from the modifyModules from the ServerWorkingCopy which modifies the lost of modules associated with the server. Also as the [modifyModules](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/wst/api/org/eclipse/wst/server/core/IServerWorkingCopy.html#modifyModules(org.eclipse.wst.server.core.IModule[],%20org.eclipse.wst.server.core.IModule[],%20IProgressMonitor)) form the ServerWorkingCopy specifies, remember to do a Save and a publish to sync up with the server. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @MPar, works adding ``workingCopy.saveAll(true, null); myServer.publish(); project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, null); `` just after invoking the ``workingCopy.modifyModule(new IModule[] {}, new IModule[]{module}, null);``